# Check / Improve a Proof - Convex functional on convex domain is continuous throughout its interior

Tags: analysis

I am working through Luenberger's Vector Space Methods for Optimization book.  I am working on a corollary left to the reader, and I'm not quite sure that my proof is correct/the sharpest proof out there.  I'd love to get some feedback from people if you're interested.  Here it is:

$\bf{Claim}$: Let $X$ be a normed linear space.  Let $C \subset X$ be a finite-dimensional and convex subset, and let $\mathring{C}$ be its relative interior. If a functional $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex, then $f$ is continuous throughout $\mathring{C}$.

$\bf{Proof}$: I treat $C$ as a metric space in its own right so that I don't have to worry about relative interiors.  I make use of the following facts (These are facts that I can prove, and I won't regurgitate them, but they are all in Luenberger pp. 192-194).

1. If $f$ is continuous at a single point, then it is continuous throughout $\mathring{C}$.
2. If $x_0 \in C$ and there exists a neighborhood $N$ containing $x_0$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq \epsilon$ for all $x \in N$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. ****I am pretty sure this is equivalent to there being an $r$ such that $(r,x_0)$ is in the relative interior of $[f,C]$, the epigraph of $f$, but I am not 100% sure, though I don't think that actually matters for the truth of the claim.

Without loss of generality, assume by translation that $0 \in C$ and $f(0) = 0$. Let $\{x_i\}$ be a basis of $C$,  and put $M = \max_i\{|f(x_i)|\}$.  Pick $x \in C$, which can be written as $\sum \alpha_ix_i$.  By convexity and translation,

$ f \big(x\big) = f \big(\sum \alpha_ix_i\big) = f \big(\sum \alpha_ix_i + (1-\sum \alpha_i)\cdot0\big) \leq \sum\alpha_if(x_i) \leq M\sum|\alpha_i|$.

Since $0 \in \mathring{C}$, there's a bounded open ball $N \subset C$ around $0$, and, since $N$ is bounded, there is a $\delta > 0$ so that for any $x = \sum\alpha_ix_i \in N$ it must be that $\max_i\{|\alpha_i|\} < \delta$. It follows that for any $x$ in $N$, $ f \big(x\big) \leq \dim\{C\} \cdot \delta \cdot M$.

QED.

Comment: I see one issue here - to apply convexity one needs $\alpha_i\ge 0$ and $1-\sum\alpha_i\ge 0$. Can you assure that?

Comment: Hmm excellent point. So we can definitely just write $M=\max\{\max\{|f(x_i)|\}, \max\{|f(-x_i)|\}\}$ and then anytime we have a negative alpha we can just write $\alpha_ix_i = (-\alpha_i) \cdot (-x_i)$...then just choose a small enough neighborhood $N$ so that $\sum|\alpha_i| \leq 1$ (or equivalently $\max\{\alpha_i\} \leq \frac{1}{\dim{C}}$).  That fixes the problem does it not?

Comment: If $-x_i \in C$... Well, with minor troubles this is the right idea. All you need is to show that $f$ is bounded above somewhere around the point. Since the (relative) interior of $C$ is non-empty you can fit inside a small simplex, e.g. a (relative) hypercube, around the point, and express the point as a convex combination of the (finite number of) extreme points (then $\alpha_i$ are "nice" by construction), then use the definition of convexity.

Comment: Yes, once translated to the origin you can pick your basis vectors so that for each $x$, $-x$ is also in $C$.  Thank you for the feedback.